# jQuery event listener basic understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I wanted to get a fuller understanding of how Javascript handles events. `click()` triggers a div to pop up, but once that div is closed it doesn't respond to the event again.

What is a good way to keep this event loop going?

```
    $project.click(function() { 
        $popup = $(".popup");
            $np.hide();
    $popup.append($html);

    // EXIT THE POPUP
        $(document).bind('keydown',function(e) { 
        if (e.which == 27) { 
            $popup.hide();
            $np.show("slow");
        }
    });
        $(".exitbutton").click(function() { 
            $popup.hide();
            $np.show("slow");   
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ? `js` appears to add a `keydown` event at each `click` ?

Comment: So the issue is the div pops up only once when the button is clicked and no more times?

Answer (score 0):

If `.popup` element is set to `display:none` at page load, can try using `.toggle()` at `$project` `click` handler. Also defined `$popup` , moved `keydown` event to outside of `click` handler, where appears to be added as `event` handler at each `click` of `$project`

```
var $popup = $(".popup");
$project.click(function() { 
    $np.toggle();
    $popup.append($html).toggle();
});

// EXIT THE POPUP
$(document).bind("keydown",function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 27) { 
        $popup.hide();
        $np.show("slow");
    }
});

$(".exitbutton").click(function() { 
    $popup.hide();
    $np.show("slow");   
});
```

Comment: Ahh yes the $popup definition should be inside in the handler. So these functions are constantly "listening" for these events?

Comment: @KyleDewhurst Can you include `html` at Question ?